# In OpenLayers 3, how do I draw an extent as a LinearRect?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, features, openlayers

In OpenLayers 2, this was an easy feat. I was able to simply instantiate a LinearRect given the coordinates of my BoundingBox, and then add the LinearRect as a feature to a vector layer I had added to the map. In OpenLayers 3, I can't seem to find any easy way to do this using extents. Say I have the current extent (it is transformed to match OSM, since the back-end for this application serves EPSG:4326):

```
# Colorado Springs
extent = ol.proj.transformExtent([aoi.west, aoi.south, aoi.east, aoi.north], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913")
```

I am trying to add this extent to the map using the following code:

```
lr = new ol.geom.LinearRing([
  [aoi.west, aoi.north],
  [aoi.east, aoi.north],
  [aoi.west, aoi.south],
  [aoi.east, aoi.south]
]).transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913")

layer = new ol.layer.Vector
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
  style: new ol.style.Style
    fill: new ol.style.Stroke
      color: '#ffcc33'
      width: 2
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke
      color: '#ffcc33'
      width: 2
    image: new ol.style.Circle
      radius: 7
      fill: new ol.style.Fill
        color: '#ffcc33'
  features: [
    new ol.Feature
      color: '#BADA55'
      where: 'inner'
      geometry: lr
  ]

map.addLayer(layer)
```

There are no errors thrown – the only problem is that the shape is not displayed on the map (although the base OSM layer is). Checking the maps layers (`console.log map.getLayers().getArray()`) reveals that the vector layer is making its way into the map.

For reference, the `aoi` object looks like this:

```
aoi = { west: -104.8, south: 39.8, east: -104.7, north: 39.9 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the features object to the `ol.layer.Vector` object, but you should pass it to the `ol.source.Vector` object instead. I don't understand how it does not throw any errors as you at least miss commas between object properties.

Comment: I moved the features array into the initialization of `ol.source.Vector`. Still nothing on the map (as far as I can tell), but now I get an assertion error when I traverse the part of the map where the vector should be (it contains no details or stack trace). Also, the reason there are missing commas is because I'm using CoffeeScript.

Comment: Can you try with something else than LinearRing? A point will do, just to be sure we're creating the geometry right. A jsfiddle would be useful btw.

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle, but couldn't find an easy way to include OpenLayers (to ensure my example actually worked)! OpenLayers 3 doesn't seem to be on a CDN yet. However, creating a single `ol.geom.Point` with the coordinates `[aoi.west, aoi.north]` worked (after transforming the projection). I tried converting all coordinates in the LinearRing to transformed `Point`s, but I'm getting assertion errors again. It seems as though I need to pass in `Coordinate`s, but I'm not sure how to create a list of coordinates.

Comment: Where does aoi variable come from?

Comment: I showed its definition in my original post. It's a bounding box representing Colorado Springs – coordinates are in EPSG:4326.

Comment: For the record, here's my latest attempt – this is just giving me a useless assertion error https://gist.github.com/stevenpetryk/f69848ffbff27d7c4fc4

Comment: Here's what I would try: Get ol.extent object. Transform it to whatever crs you need. Build an array of coordinates by calling extent.getBottomLeft(), extent.getTopLeft(), extent.getTopRight() and extent.getBottomRight(). Pass this array as input to ol.geom.LinearRing object. I guess order of mentioned functions should not matter.

Comment: Did you read the docs btw? *Linear ring geometry. Only used as part of polygon; cannot be rendered on its own.* I recommend creating a polygon or linestring instead of linearring.

Comment: LinearString worked like a charm! Just had to add another point so it would get closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to render this as a polygon, you need to enclose the coordinates in an additional pair of square brackets:

```
lr = new ol.geom.Polygon([[
  [aoi.west, aoi.north],
  [aoi.east, aoi.north],
  [aoi.west, aoi.south],
  [aoi.east, aoi.south]
]]).transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913")
```